# How build uncompressed (uncompiled) angular-spring-data-rest.js from angular-spring-data-rest repository?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, bower, spring-data-rest

Here is [anular-spring-data-rest](https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest) repository. How to build `angular-spring-data-rest.js`? Yep, I see `bower` and `npm` commands but where do they store the built `js` file (also how to build uncompressed version)? Personally, I am not familiar with these tools, but I need the uncompiled (uncompressed) js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) build tool. They have registered 3 task in [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) build, test and default

So you need grunt installed globally also

```
$ npm install gulp -g
$ cd angular-spring-data-rest
$ npm install # to install repo dependencies 
$ gulp # or gulp build
$ cd dist
```

Comment: Could please clarify where npm stores gulp after command `npm install gulp -g` is executed?

Comment: Surprisingly there is already populated [dist](https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest/tree/master/dist) folder in git repository. :)

Comment: `npm list -g` will list the global packages you install